# particles come together to build text

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

So I am trying to create a cloud of particles that come together to make  text for a little end card for a school video project and I found a video that does basically the opposite effect.

I was wondering if there is a way to reverse that effect without literally reversing the frames. The only reason i can't do that is because i also have some dust specs floating around in the background using depth of field so i can't mask the text and composite or some other wizardry as far as i know.

Here is the link to the opposite of the effect i want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q93pE5jB1Uw&t=234s

Comment: You are looking for Keyed Particles. [Here](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/properties/physics/keyed.html) is the Blender Manual page on them. Google around and find a tutorial on them.

Comment: Thank you Scott, this looks like exactly what i need. Thanks for the help man.